# Activities not applying themes correctly on tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

All my activities are set in AndroidManifest.xml to      `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`.
They apply the style correctly on phones I tested so far, however when I tested on tablets (API 21, API 23) some activities have light-grey background instead of white. The theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

I dealt with it by setting the white background color programmatically in my `BaseActivity` like so:

```
public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
    View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

and then calling it inside `onCreate()` method. I'm puzzled however at the difference in behavior in phones and tablets. I have tested on devices (pairs: phone\tablet) with the same APIs and they differ. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm a bit color blind. I couldn't notice the difference on phones, but when I took some screenshots and compared the look of activities it turned out that the activities were colored the same way on phones and tablets. Still puzzled as to why some were applying `AppTheme` correctly and others did not. Any ideas?